# Formal proof for continuity/limit

Tags: functions, continuity

A function is said to be continuous at point $a$ if for all $δ > 0$ there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $∀x ∈ \mathbb{R},$ $|x − a| < \varepsilon$ implies $|f(x) − f(a)| < δ$.

Show formally that this implies that the sequence $y_n = f\left(a + \frac{1}{n}\right)$ converges to $f(a)$.

Comment: I suspect you mean "sequence" and not "series" here. What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What have you tried? The more you can tell us about your thoughts and efforts, the more easily we can tailor our answers to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\delta_1,\epsilon$ be such that $|x-a|<\delta_1\Rightarrow|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$. We wish to find $N$ such that $n,m>N\Rightarrow|f(a+\frac{1}{n})-f(a)|<\epsilon$. Let $N=\frac{1}{\delta}$. Since $n>\frac{1}{\delta}$, we have that $|\frac{1}{n}|<\delta$, and so $|a+\frac{1}{n}-a|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(a+\frac{1}{n})-f(a)|<\epsilon$, so we are done.

Answer (score 0):

We know that for all $\delta >0$ there exists a number $\epsilon>0$ such that whenever $|x-a|<\epsilon$,

$$|f(x)-f(a)|<\delta$$

Obviously, if $n>\frac1{\epsilon}$, then $\left|\left(a+\frac1n\right)-a\right|=\frac1n <\epsilon$.  So, for the given $\delta>0$,

$$\left|f\left(a+\frac1n\right)-f(a)\right|<\delta$$

whenever $n>\frac1{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  - Mark